# how to re-try/catch input mismatch exception without getting caught by infinite loop

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to take input from the user to build a grid for a 2d mine's weeper game,
the process goes pretty smooth when I pass valid values to the Scanner, but when I try invalid things it goes through infinite loop even the try block is try with resources which should close the scanner with each a new try, it sounds it doesn't close it when it prints the string on the catch infinitely

```
int gridSize = 0;
    System.out.println("how much do you want the grid's size");
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        while (gridSize == 0) {
            gridSize = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.next();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("try again");
    }
```

Comment: You should never need to catch `NoSuchElementException`, since you should use `scanner.hasNextInt()` to check token before calling `nextInt()`.

Comment: When the next token is not an `int` token, you need to discard the token by calling either `next()` or `nextLine()`.

Comment: shouldn't the try with resources close it?

Comment: I was referring to the `catch (NoSuchElementException e)`, not the try-with-resources part. But to answer that question, in general, no you should not close a `Scanner` that is wrapping `System.in`, since closing `System.in` is not your responsibility, and closing it commonly leads to errors.

Comment: How about using [`Scanner#hasNextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) to check whether the input is in the format you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're catching the wrong exception - if the input isn't an `int`, an [`InputMismatchException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) will be thrown. But regardless, this can be made easier by using [`hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--):

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.err.println("Try again, this time with a proper int");
        scanner.next();
    }
    gridSize = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: yeah it goes well, but shouldn't it be with a catch block

Comment: @همامبابيخوجة No. `hashNextInt()` will just return `false` if you input something that isn't an `int`. No need to catch an exception.

Comment: I tried while (!scanner.hasNextInt()||scanner.nextInt()>10) to be sure the input is less than 10, it goes well then but it takes the input two times